# Power Bi DAX Decimal Rounding

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I created a measure using joined tables to show me a rate of something. The problem I'm having is that the rounding of my value is always 2 places. It's a very finite rate that requires at least 3 rounding places.

I've tried using `ROUND`, but that doesn't work. I've included a screen cap of my visual and my measure.

[image: Card Visual]

[image: Measure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ROUND` function does round it to 4 decimal places but what you want is to *format* it to show more decimal places.

Select your measure and go to the **Modeling** table at the top. There's a **Formatting** section that will allow you to change the format the measure uses to display.

Comment: Wow you're absolutely right. Such an oversight on my part. My problem was that I had the visual highlighted and not the measure. 

Thank you